# Getgting Userinfo in Keycloak 21.1.1 using Service Access Token

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

I'm working with Keycloak version 21.1.1 and I have a client that has been granted a service access token. I would like to use this token to create a new user programmatically. How can I create a user in Keycloak using the service access token?

Here's what I have tried so far:

Obtained the service access token for my client. Made a POST request to the Keycloak API /auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users endpoint with the necessary user data and included the service access token in the Authorization header. However, I'm receiving an "403" when trying to create the user.

Could you please provide guidance on the correct approach to create a user using the service access token in Keycloak 21.1.1? Any code examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!